# How do I file a bug for a trackpad?

Tags: bug-reporting, trackpad

I believe I've found a regression in click-and-drag on my laptop's trackpad, and it's proving to be very annoying. I'd like to file a bug, but I have no idea what package I should file against.

I've already taken a look at [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/18612), but didn't find what I was looking for there. The [top-rated answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/5126/18612) suggests https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bugs/FindRightPackage to determine what package I need to file against, but there's no mention of trackpads there, either.

Comment: What laptop have you got?

Comment: @sakjur It's a Toshiba Satellite A505-S6960.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to file the bug against `xorg-xserver-input-synaptics` as shown [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/938746). I guess I'll know based on feedback from the devs whether this is the right package.

**UPDATE:** This bug was almost immediately marked a duplicate of [Bug 934770](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/934770), which currently requires feedback to decide whether to revert the relevant default setting or not. At least I now know for sure that I filed against the correct package.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be one of the Xorg packages. Search Launchpad for Xorg bugs and you will probably find a report very similar that you can add your info to. Or at least see what to file your bug against.